# Android: Check HW Encoder or SW Encoder used in MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, video-encoding, android-mediarecorder

I have used `MediaRecorder` class in Android. I have set video encoder as follows,

```
media_rec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Out of Hardware Encoder or Software Encoder which encoder is being used to encode frames in `H264`.

Is there anyways by which I can force/check only Hardware Encoder is used in this process.

Edit 1:

I tried with `MediaCodec` to get Codec Information.

```
media_codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
used_codec_name = media_codec.getName();
```

I get following as output,

```
I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded
```

As per some links from Google, `OMX.Exynos.avc.dec` is Hardware Encoder.

Question is for Recording I am using `MediaRecorder` Class. So Is it confirm that when I am recording `.mp4` file with `H264` video stream using `MediaRecorder` class it's using Hardware Encoder.

Please can someone provide me some thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but if you are using an encoder/decoder from the `omx.google` family, you are using the software version. Otherwise, it is a hardware encoder/decoder such as `omx.exynos`, `omx.qcom` etc.